# CALayer live blur inside AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-animation, calayer, caanimation

I am trying to come up with a way to perform a live blur during AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool export.  I have tried UIVisualEffectView and stealing the layer of the underlying view. It works in preview but as soon as you use it inside AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool the layer is black.  So I started building a CALayer that does this but it is not updating often enough.  What can I do to make it draw more often or what might work for using the AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool and a live blur in iOS?  Here is the layer I built.

```
class CABlurLayer : CALayer{
    let maxBlurRadius : CGFloat = 20
    var currentImageIndex : Float = 0
    var blur : Int  = 10
    var context : CGContext?
    var link : Timer?
    var snap : UIImage?
    var targetLayer : CALayer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(targetLayer:CALayer?){
        self.init()
        self.targetLayer = targetLayer
        self.drawsAsynchronously = true
        if let tl = targetLayer{
          self.masksToBounds = tl.masksToBounds
        }

        updateSnapShots()
        link = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1/60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateBlur), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateBlur(){
        updateSnapShots()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func updateSnapShots(){
        guard let tl = targetLayer else{return}
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{return}
        tl.render(in: ctx)

        let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        snap = snapshot?.applyBlurWithRadius(CGFloat(blur), tintColor: UIColor().withAlphaComponent(0), saturationDeltaFactor: 1.4)

    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        guard let blurredImage = snap,
        let tl = targetLayer else{return}
        var origin = tl.frame.origin
        if let pres = tl.presentation(){
            origin = pres.frame.origin
        }
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        blurredImage.draw(at: origin)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}


class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view
        let ur = URL(string: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: ur!) { (dt, response, error) in
            if let data = dt{
                print("we have a response")
                let img = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let layer = CALayer()
                    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
                    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

                    let imageLayer = CALayer()
                    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
                    imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 400, height: 300)
                    imageLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                    imageLayer.contents = img?.cgImage
                    layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)


                    let blur = CABlurLayer(targetLayer: imageLayer)
                    blur.frame = layer.bounds
                    layer.addSublayer(blur)
                    blur.blur = 20


                    let pos = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
                    pos.toValue = imageLayer.position.x
                    pos.fromValue = imageLayer.position.x - 100
                    pos.duration = 2
                    pos.repeatCount = 100
                    pos.autoreverses = true
                    imageLayer.add(pos, forKey: nil)
                }
            }
        }.resume()


    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

UIImage Extensions

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate

public extension UIImage {
    public func applyLightEffect() -> UIImage? {
        return applyBlurWithRadius(30, tintColor: UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3), saturationDeltaFactor: 1.8)
    }

    public func applyExtraLightEffect() -> UIImage? {
        return applyBlurWithRadius(20, tintColor: UIColor(white: 0.97, alpha: 0.82), saturationDeltaFactor: 1.8)
    }

    public func applyDarkEffect() -> UIImage? {
        return applyBlurWithRadius(20, tintColor: UIColor(white: 0.11, alpha: 0.73), saturationDeltaFactor: 1.8)
    }

    public func applyTintEffectWithColor(_ tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let effectColorAlpha: CGFloat = 0.6
        var effectColor = tintColor

        let componentCount = tintColor.cgColor.numberOfComponents

        if componentCount == 2 {
            var b: CGFloat = 0
            if tintColor.getWhite(&b, alpha: nil) {
                effectColor = UIColor(white: b, alpha: effectColorAlpha)
            }
        } else {
            var red: CGFloat = 0
            var green: CGFloat = 0
            var blue: CGFloat = 0

            if tintColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil) {
                effectColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: effectColorAlpha)
            }
        }

        return applyBlurWithRadius(10, tintColor: effectColor, saturationDeltaFactor: -1.0, maskImage: nil)
    }

    public func applyBlurWithRadius(_ blurRadius: CGFloat, tintColor: UIColor?, saturationDeltaFactor: CGFloat, maskImage: UIImage? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        // Check pre-conditions.
        if (size.width < 1 || size.height < 1) {
            print("*** error: invalid size: \(size.width) x \(size.height). Both dimensions must be >= 1: \(self)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            print("*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: \(self)")
            return nil
        }
        if maskImage != nil && maskImage!.cgImage == nil {
            print("*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: \(String(describing: maskImage))")
            return nil
        }

        let __FLT_EPSILON__ = CGFloat(Float.ulpOfOne)
        let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        var effectImage = self

        let hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__
        let hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.0) > __FLT_EPSILON__

        if hasBlur || hasSaturationChange {
            func createEffectBuffer(_ context: CGContext) -> vImage_Buffer {
                let data = context.data
                let width = vImagePixelCount(context.width)
                let height = vImagePixelCount(context.height)
                let rowBytes = context.bytesPerRow

                return vImage_Buffer(data: data, height: height, width: width, rowBytes: rowBytes)
            }

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)
            guard let effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return  nil }

            effectInContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            effectInContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: -size.height)
            effectInContext.draw(cgImage, in: imageRect)

            var effectInBuffer = createEffectBuffer(effectInContext)


            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)

            guard let effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return  nil }
            var effectOutBuffer = createEffectBuffer(effectOutContext)


            if hasBlur {
                // A description of how to compute the box kernel width from the Gaussian
                // radius (aka standard deviation) appears in the SVG spec:
                // http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement
                //
                // For larger values of 's' (s >= 2.0), an approximation can be used: Three
                // successive box-blurs build a piece-wise quadratic convolution kernel, which
                // approximates the Gaussian kernel to within roughly 3%.
                //
                // let d = floor(s * 3*sqrt(2*pi)/4 + 0.5)
                //
                // ... if d is odd, use three box-blurs of size 'd', centered on the output pixel.
                //

                let inputRadius = blurRadius * screenScale
                let d = floor(inputRadius * 3.0 * CGFloat(sqrt(2 * .pi) / 4 + 0.5))
                var radius = UInt32(d)
                if radius % 2 != 1 {
                    radius += 1 // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
                }

                let imageEdgeExtendFlags = vImage_Flags(kvImageEdgeExtend)

                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
            }

            var effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = false

            if hasSaturationChange {
                let s: CGFloat = saturationDeltaFactor
                let floatingPointSaturationMatrix: [CGFloat] = [
                    0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                    0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                    0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                    0,                    0,                    0,  1
                ]

                let divisor: CGFloat = 256
                let matrixSize = floatingPointSaturationMatrix.count
                var saturationMatrix = [Int16](repeating: 0, count: matrixSize)

                for i: Int in 0 ..< matrixSize {
                    saturationMatrix[i] = Int16(round(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor))
                }

                if hasBlur {
                    vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, Int32(divisor), nil, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
                    effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = true
                } else {
                    vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, Int32(divisor), nil, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
                }
            }

            if !effectImageBuffersAreSwapped {
                effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            }

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            if effectImageBuffersAreSwapped {
                effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            }

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        // Set up output context.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)

        guard let outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

        outputContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        outputContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: -size.height)

        // Draw base image.
        outputContext.draw(cgImage, in: imageRect)

        // Draw effect image.
        if hasBlur {
            outputContext.saveGState()
            if let maskCGImage = maskImage?.cgImage {
                outputContext.clip(to: imageRect, mask: maskCGImage);
            }
            outputContext.draw(effectImage.cgImage!, in: imageRect)
            outputContext.restoreGState()
        }

        // Add in color tint.
        if let color = tintColor {
            outputContext.saveGState()
            outputContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            outputContext.fill(imageRect)
            outputContext.restoreGState()
        }

        // Output image is ready.
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return outputImage
    }

    public func blurImage()->UIImage?{
        return self.applyBlurWithRadius(20, tintColor: UIColor().withAlphaComponent(0), saturationDeltaFactor: 1.4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been around a while so I thought I would share my solution.  I stole the CABackdropLayer from a UIVisualEffectView to achieve a live blur. You can init a layer of this type but it is private. However since a public view uses this layer and I am just taking it from that view I am not having to access a private api in a super direct way.